# Download PDF file in Flex with HTTPService

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, httpservice

Hi
Someone know how to download a pdf file with HTTPService?
I do that

```
private function downloadPDF():void
{
    var httpService:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
    httpService.url = "http://coenraets.org/flexandroid90/FlexAndroid90Minutes.pdf";
    httpService.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, result);
    httpService.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, fault);
    httpService.send();
}

private function fault(event:FaultEvent):void
{
    trace("Error");
    trace("\t> Code : "+event.fault.faultCode);
    trace("\t> Description : "+event.fault.faultString);
    trace("\t> Detail : "+event.fault.faultDetail);
}

private function result(event:ResultEvent):void
{
    var pdfFile:File = new File(File.applicationStorageDirectory.nativePath + File.separator + "myPDF.pdf");
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.open(pdfFile, FileMode.WRITE);
    fileStream.writeUTFBytes(event.result as String);
    fileStream.close();
}
```

But I got an error

> Error
>   Code : Client.CouldNotDecode
>   Description : Error #1090: XML parser failure: element is malformed.
>   Detail : null

With URLLoader it works fine

```
private function initPDF():void
{
    loader = new downloadPDF();
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://coenraets.org/flexandroid90/FlexAndroid90Minutes.pdf");
    configureListeners(loader);
    try {
        loader.load(request);
    } catch (error:Error) {
        trace("Unable to load requested URL.");
    }
}

private function configureListeners(dispatcher:EventDispatcher):void {
    dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    dispatcher.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
}

private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    var pdfFile:File = new File(File.applicationStorageDirectory.nativePath + File.separator + "myPDF.pdf");
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.open(pdfFile, FileMode.WRITE);
    fileStream.writeBytes(loader.data);
    fileStream.close();
}

private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
    trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
}
```

Comment: HTTPService is used to call a web service that will return you data in text or XML form. It's actually a query to a server (not to a database, don't get me wrong).

Why do you want to use a service instead of the regular URLLoader?

Comment: I have been ask to use a HTTPService if possible. But I will use URLLoader

Comment: @Snote, you can get binary data over HTTPService too, check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can.

You just need to add
`httpService.resultFormat="text"`

This will just give you the string response without parsing it as an xml. Though not recommended because HTTPService is meant for WebServices, it CAN be done

Comment: +1 Yeah, HTTPService has a different purpose. If you're going for loading binaries, use URLLoader instead. Using HTTPService is likely instantiating more than you need. Whoever told you to use HTTPService needs to know the difference.

Comment: HTTPService could be useful when the binary resource is on a different host that is not directly accessible by the client.. its a cheap and fast way to proxy and serve these resources without relying on a real, external proxy.

Answer (score -1):

The thing is you can't download something that isn't text or XML (so, it's text) using HTTPLoader.